# Using __LINE__ macro as a template parameter in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I expected the following code to work, but I received a compile error:

> ```
> error C2975: 'n' : invalid template argument for 'foo', expected compile-time constant expression
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N>
struct foo
{
    foo() { cout << N << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    foo< __LINE__ > f;
}
```

Why does this happen?  I though `__LINE__` would paste in the line number before template instantiation occurred?

If I wanted to do this should I just introduce a `static const int` to hold the line number or is there a standard solution?

Comment: What version? Works in VS2010. (I have done this before, but tried your code anyway.)

Comment: @GMan: Interesting, tested too in VS2010 and it doesn't work for me. o_O (Or do you mean with the `static const int` defined in global scope? Which would actually defeat the purpose...)

Comment: @GMan:  I'm running a clean install of 2010.

Comment: @Bob: @Xeo: Wtf...What version? Mine's: "10.0.30319.1 RTMRel".

Comment: @Xeo: That's very wrong, then. Do you guys have the service pack installed? (I don't.)

Comment: @GMan: Not that I know of. Of course VS could've installed it without me realizing, but I don't think so.

Comment: @Xeo: Hm. Can you run the Visual Studio Command Line and run "cl"? My reports version: "16.00.30319.01".

Comment: @GMan: I have the same version of visual studio and the compiler as you.  I don't have the service pack installed.

Comment: @Bob: If you are enabling `/ZI` (edit and continue debugging) option, does
disabling this solve the problem?

Comment: @Bob @Xeo: Try this: Go to your Project Property Pages, expand the C/C++ folder, go to General and set "Suppress Startup Banner" to "No". This will cause the compiler to show its version number to the Output window when you compile. That way you get the version number of the compiler Visual Studio is actually using.

Comment: @Bob:  Is your `#define` for `__LINE__` somehow different from ours?  Right click on `__LINE__` and select "go to declaration".

Comment: @John: That's built into the language (compiler), you can't see its declaration.

Comment: @Ise, @Bob:  Well I don't get that one bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works for me in VS 2010 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel and in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rjb3U)

**But MSDN mentions problems** which result in C2975, if using `__LINE__` in template with compiler-option `/ZI`: [MSDN C2975](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kyf0z2ka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Edit: Sorry, I linked the german version, [here in english](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyf0z2ka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Works without `/ZI` for me too.

Comment: Good find! It also makes sense, if you are going to allow for *edit and continue* debugging, `__LINE__` cannot be a compile time constant, since the actual line of code can be changed in a debugging session.

Comment: I had to use the `/Zi` option by doing the following : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521991/1294758

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this is suppose to be valid code. `__LINE__` is suppose to behave as if it were:

```
#define __LINE__ 0
```

Of course, replacing 0 with the current line number.

Comment: @In: Why are we the lucky ones? :)

Comment: @GMan: Apparently because we don't use the `/ZI` flag. :-)

Comment: @In: Ah, because we don't make mistakes and have no need for that option, right? :)

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that it works in 14.00.50727.762 (VC8, SP1) and 15.00.30729.01 (VC9, SP1).

Comment: Not the answer it turns out, but worth a +1 regardless

Comment: @GMan: Well actually it's because `/ZI` doesn't work for 64-bit targets, but I'll go with your reason. :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Bob, you are going to *love* this one!

I was interested in your question so I tried your code. It compiled in g++ but fails with your error in MSVC10. To investigate, I used Google to find out how to see the preprocessor output: you set "Properties | C++ | Preprocessor | Preprocess to a file" to true. And then I compiled again... AND IT WORKED! Turns out if this option is disabled, the compile fails; if it's enabled, the compile works. I suppose MS doesn't bother to generate **LINE** entries unless the preprocessor output is being captured. Oy va voy!

Comment: You "suppose" incorrectly.  I've used `__LINE__` about a million times.

Comment: And you don't suppose those folks have that option turned on?