# VC++ : Invalid template argument

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to rebuild an old VC++ project in VS 2010. Its currently spitting out an `Invalid template argument` error.

Do I have to add a [`.template` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344954/1294758)? Where?

The full error is below:

> Error C2975: 'N' : invalid template argument for ToChunkFunc, expected compile-time constant expression

Comment: Can you [fill in this semi compilable example of your code so it reproduces your error?](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3yahBj$8)

Comment: I have a feeling it's because `__LINE__` may not be considered a compile time constant.

Comment: Yes, when I click it and press F4 (goto definition), VS says `"cannot locate definition for __LINE__"`. I think this lib was built with VC9, and expects `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to already exist as preprocessor keywords or whatever.... What does it usually stand for?

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397782/using-line-macro-as-a-template-parameter-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Geotarget `__LINE__` is a macro that expands to be the current line number in the `__FILE__` which expands to be a filename.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: `__LINE__` _is_ a compile time constant because as a predefined macro it is replaced at preprocessing time, i.e. before "real" compilation even happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error `C2975` can be caused when the `__LINE__` keyword is unavailable. If edit and continue is turned on, the compiler is run with the `/ZI` option which enables creation of a **program database** rather than a **PDB file**, in this mode the `__LINE__` constant is unavailable because the line numbers can change at runtime. You'll need to use the `/Zi` command line option which has support for the `__LINE__` constant.

To set this compiler option in the VS IDE:

1. Open `Project Settings` > `C/C++` > `General`.
2. Modify the Debug Information Format property.